Preliminary lemma to Hahn's decomposition theorem
Lemma Suppose that $\nu$ is a signed measure on a measurable space $(X,\mathcal{A})$. If $A\in\mathcal{A}$ and $\nu(A)\in (0,\infty)$, then there exists a positive subset $P\subseteq A$ such that $\nu(P)>0$.
Proof. We suppose that $\nu(E)\in [-\infty,\infty)$ for all $E\in\mathcal{A}$. Let $B\in\mathcal{A}$ such that $B\subseteq A$, then $\nu(B)\ne \infty$, also we have that $$\nu(B)=\nu(A)-\nu(A\setminus B)\ne-\infty$$ since $\nu(A)$ is finite and $\nu(A\setminus B)\ne\infty$.
Let $$\delta_1=\inf\{\nu(E)\;|\; E\in\mathcal{A}, E\subseteq A\}.$$ Then $-\infty\le \delta_1 \le 0$ since $\emptyset\subset A$. Choose $A_1\subseteq A$ such that $\delta_1 \le \nu(A_1)\le \delta_1/2$ if $\delta_1$ is finite, or $\nu(A_1)\le -1$ if $\delta_1=-\infty$. Define a disjoint sequence of subsetes $\{A_i\subseteq A\;|\; i\in\mathbb{N}\}$ inductively by setting $$\delta_i=\inf\left\{\nu(E)\;\; E\in\mathcal{A}, E\subseteq A\setminus\left(\bigcup_{j=1}^{i-1}A_j\right)\right\}$$ and choosing $A_i\subseteq A\setminus\left(\bigcup_{j=1}^{i-1}A_j\right)$ such that $$\delta_1\le \nu(A_i)\le\delta_i/2$$ if $-\infty<\delta_i\le 0$ pr $\nu(A_i)\le 1$ if $\delta_i=-\infty$. Let $$B=\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty A_i,\qquad P=A\setminus B.$$ Then, since the $A_i$ are disjoined, we have $$\nu(B)=\sum_{i=1}^\infty \nu(A_i).$$ As proved, $\nu(B)$ is finite, so this negative sum must converge. It follows that $\nu(A_i)\le -1$ for only finitely many $i$, and therefore $\delta_i$ is infinite for at most finitely many $i$. For the remainig $i$ we have $$-\infty<\sum\nu (A_i)\le \frac{1}{2}\color{green}{\sum_{-\infty<\delta_i\le 0}\delta_i}\le 0$$ so $\sum_{-\infty<\delta_i\le 0} \delta_i$ converges and therefore $\delta_i\to 0$ as $i\to \infty$.
If $E\subseteq P$, then $\nu(E)\ge \delta_i$ for all $i\in \mathbb{N}$, in fact we have that
$$E\subseteq P = A\ /\left(\bigcup_{j=1}^{\infty}A_i\right) \subseteq A\ / \left(\bigcup_{j=1}^{i-1}A_j\right).$$
In the notes it says that $\nu(E)\ge \delta_i$ for every sufficiently large $i\in\mathbb{N}$

Question Why do need to say that $\nu(E)\ge \delta_i$ for every sufficiently large $i\in\mathbb{N}$

My answer is as follows: We don't know if the whole sequence $\{\delta_i\}_{i\in\mathbb{N}}$ convergers to $0$, because by the convergence of the series in green we only know that the subsequence $\{\delta_i\;|\; -\infty< \delta_i\le 0\}$ of the sequence $\{\delta_i\}$ converges to $0$. So, certainly $\nu(E)\ge \delta_i$ for all $i\in\mathbb{N}$, in particular $$\nu(E)\ge \delta_i$$ for all $i\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $-\infty<\delta_i\le 0$ and the since the sequence $\{\delta_i\;|\; -\infty< \delta_i\le 0\}$ converges to $0$ we have that $\nu(E)\ge 0$.
I've already read this post, but I need a more formal reason.

At least I don't think your answer is the case. You assume $\delta_i$ are finitely $-\infty$. Therefore for sufficiently large $i$, $\delta_i$ must be finite, and hence converges to $0$.
The fact $\nu(E)\ge\delta_i$ should be coupled with the fact $\delta_i\to0$, which means $\nu(E)\ge0$ for all $E\subseteq P$ measurable, which concludes the property that $P$ is positive.
